# Horizontal lazy load on div with onScreen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the onScroll plugin working with my horizontal webpage that is something like that :

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="column"><p>01</p></div>
    <div class="column"><p>02</p></div>
    <div class="column"><p>03</p></div>
    <div class="column"><p>04</p></div>
    <div class="column"><p>05</p></div>
    <div class="column"><p>06</p></div>
    <div class="column"><p>07</p></div>
    <div class="column"><p>08</p></div>
    <div class="column"><p>09</p></div>
    <div class="column"><p>10</p></div>
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle shot of what I have : EDIT HERE IS THE LAST ONE -> http://jsfiddle.net/UcQpA/7/

My goal is to get something similar to this demo with the onScroll plugin :
http://silvestreh.github.io/onScreen/horizontal.html

Unfortunately, as the website of the demo is made with HTML5 and mine with XHTML, I don't understand how it's actually working.

Could you please help me ?

Thank you ! :)

Comment: XHTML and HTML5 shouldn't differ too much in syntax; what's the problem exactly? It's just that you don't understand what to do at all?

Comment: There's no concrete explanation on how to use the plugin. That's the reason why i'm trying to imitate the code via the view-source of this page : http://silvestreh.github.io/onScreen/horizontal.html

Comment: Just as a question, can you switch to HTML5?

Comment: I've made some updates on the jsfiddle page, using the code of the plugin demo.
http://jsfiddle.net/ftnX9/5/

Comment: No, I can't switch, unfortunately.

Comment: Haha, this is above me at the moment. Not even sure if JsFiddle can handle this (Although I don't see why not)

Comment: ok, maybe I should give up... ;)

Comment: :\ I'm sorry about that. I'll see what I can do; this would be really beneficial for me as well

Comment: Check out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931264/lazy-load-blog-posts

Comment: from links to links, i found this : http://jsfiddle.net/addiktedDesign/KjNnY/ but i need a solution for an horizontal scrolling...

Comment: I think that I'm a bit closer from what I would like... http://jsfiddle.net/UcQpA/7/

Comment: What else are you going for?

Comment: Hey! I'm the developer of this plugin. What is exactly that you're trying to accomplish? Loading more items once you get to the last one?