# Lazy load and unload of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I have an html file with many  tags.

I want to load images on scroll event, and unload the images which are not visible.
like in Aamzaon viewer, when you scroll up/down, the current image in the frame is lazy loaded.

I saw a lot of LazyLoad tools, but no one of them has unload functionallity.

Comment: So what are you looking for here?

Comment: and the question is....??

Comment: Why exactly would you like to unload ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553528/how-can-i-set-divs-to-visibilityhidden-if-they-are-outside-of-viewport

Comment: Obviously, I am looking for a plugin or code that implement this functionallity...
@mplungjan thanks for the reference, but I don't want to hide the content, I want to remove it.

Comment: @Gupta.Swap I can have really big documents (every page is an image) and I want good performance. In amazon, when you open a book with a lot of pages, every page is loaded according to the scroller

Answer (score 2):

Use this plugins jquery: https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear
And use event: appear to display images and disappear to unload images:

```
$('someselector').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
  // this element is now inside browser viewport
});
$('someselector').on('disappear', function(event, $all_disappeared_elements) {
  // this element is now outside browser viewport
});
```

Comment: Then your test results?

Comment: Hi Eric, I decided to use LazyLoad and I just changed this code to do "unload" too. Thanks anyway for the help! :)

Comment: @Inbal Might I ask how you modified the lazyload plugin? I tried just adding `$this.attr("src", settings.placeholder);` to the "if abovethefold" condition, but it seems it may be a bit more complex than that...? the update doesn't seem to get triggered after the images have been lazy-loaded once

Comment: @IainMullan I binded another event named "disappear", which is the same as "appear", instead of the "src". I change the src attr back to the animated gif. and my "update" function looks like this: if above or below - trigger disappear, else trigger appear

Comment: @Inbal do you mind sharing your fork of appear.js if you still have it?