# multiple images load on html page fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

Right now I am showing image through normal image tag :-

```
<img src="xyz.com/abc.jpg" rel="name" />
```

So when only 2 or 5 image on page then It's showing fast But We have more than 1000 images and it's take lot's of time for showing on page.

How I can load this page very fast and show these 1000 images ?

Any lead highly appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: How about __Lazy-loading__ ?

Comment: Take a look at [Lazy Loading](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Comment: Suppose lazy-loading could be useful in your case. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192651/load-lazy-loading-a-div-whenever-the-div-gets-visible-for-the-first-time

Comment: Lazy-loading like other have pointed out is a good idea, you normally load extra images on page scroll.  But if your images are small and the same size, you could use a technique known as tiled images.  This is basically one big image, that then can be split into smaller ones using CSS.  Some frameworks use this technique for doing icons etc.

Comment: Also another option!!, that works with modern browsers is HTTP/2 & SPDY.  This is something you need to setup your Web Server to handle.

Comment: Rayon , Coss @Keith Thank for support, we have already used thumbnail but Customer want to show full size of image and per image size is max 1MB....and we have already send many ajax request on same page..

Comment: @VDWWD Thank for support. How do sites like shutterstock load fast?

Comment: By not putting 1000 images on one page. Also the smaller the images the faster they load of course. So you could create thumbnails or rezise and/or reduce the quality server side.

Comment: @VDWWD yes same think I want to do it but Customer want to show full size of images :(